# JavaScript: Do I need a recursive function to solve this problem?

Tags: javascript

In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5L8Q8/28/, if you click the black button, it randomly selects one of two values (red or blue) from an array. The randomly selected value is assigned to `ran`. In my real life application, there will be 16 elements in that array.

If you the pink "playagain" button, it chooses a random element from the same array but I want to make sure it's not the same one chosen as last time.

Therefore, when I click `playagain`, I assign `ran` to `lastran` and compare it to the next randomly chosen value from the array and, if they are the same, choose randomly again. However, the way I have it isn't guaranteeing that (upon the completion of `playagain`) `ran` is different.

I think I need a recursive function where comment 2 is in the code below, but I keep breaking my code when I try to create it.

Can you comment on the 3 comments in the code below?

Note, I'm a relative newbie, so this code is probably awful...

```
$("#playagain").click(function(){
    lastran = ran; 


    ran = getRandom(myArray, true);

    if (ran === lastran) { 

        ran = getRandom(myArray, true); //1. do I need to return this?

           //2. want to test ran === lastran again.. How to set up recursive function?

    } else {

       return; //3.is this the right thing to do here?
    }  

});
```

Comment: Don't worry, everyone is a relative newbie, even those people who think they aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a while loop instead of the if.

```
while(ran == lastran)
{
  ran = getRandom(myArray, true);
}
```

It'll keep trying until it gets a different value.

Comment: I was saying you can change the if to this while. Which is true. Yes you need that ran=getRandom(...). It can be one line, but I think this is "easier" to understand why a while loop works and recursion isn't necessary.

Comment: is this how you imagined it?  http://jsfiddle.net/5L8Q8/31/   I think it's fine...

Answer (score 3):

```
while( (ran = getRandom(myArray, true)) === lastran)
    ;
```

Is what you want. The statement

```
ran = getRandom(myArray, true)
```

does not only set `ran` to `getRandom()`, but returns the value of `ran`. (This is a fairly common idiom in JavaScript, a carry over from C.)

So your full code can be:

```
$("#playagain").click(function(){
    /*var */lastran = ran; 

    while( (ran = getRandom(myArray, true)) === lastran)
        ;

    // update UI here

});
```

Comment: thank you very much. Edgar also answered correctly so I flipped a coin to see who gets "accepted answer." unfortunately you lost but thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Edgar's code does not actually work :( You'll need to add one more `ran = getRandom(myAray, true)` to the start of his code if you want to use his method.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. @Michael though, please remember this technique when you read other people's code.

Comment: @luxun: You may want to take another look at *your* code. You're missing a closing `)`. Depending on its placement, you'll get different results.

Comment: when I added the closing ) that @patrick dw referred to, it said that random was "false" in the final alert

Comment: @Michael: You'll need to add it *before* the `===` instead of after the `lastran`.

Answer (score 1):

After each run, simply remove that "key" from array and push lastran to the end of it. Then the updated getRandom function as following could be used both for #button and #playagain. http://jsfiddle.net/ghostoy/5L8Q8/32/

```
function getRandom(array, getVal) {
    var key = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length),
        value = array[key];

    if (lastran) {
        array.push(lastran);
    }

    array.splice(key, 1);
    lastran = value;

    if (getVal) {
        return value; 
    }
    return key; 
}
```

Comment: +1. Much better to remove the chosen value from the array so that the next selection can't be the same as the last one. Could either keep a copy of the original array, or put the selected ones into a new array. When the first is exhausted, swap it with the selections. So you fill one while emptying the other, then do it in reverse. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is not the best way to deal with this. In theory you could get the same number many times in a row making this a 'slow' algorythm and you are making it more complex than needed.

An alternative approach in text:

```
- if no previous element has been picked pick a number between 0 and the number of elements in your array (16) otherwise pick a number between 0 and #elements-1 (15)
- if the chosen element is greater or equal to the last element picked add 1 to it 
- store this index number as the last picked element
- return the array[picked-element]'s value
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make `getRandom` itself recursive:

```
function getRandom(array, getVal, lastRan) { 
    var key = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
    if ((!getVal && key == lastRan) || (getVal && array[key] == lastRan))
        return getRandom(array, getVal, lastRan);
    return getVal ? array[key] : key;
}
```

Call it passing the last random value:

```
getRandom(myArray, true, lastran)
```

It works like this. You always pass `getRandom` the last random value that was retrieved. In the first conditional, we check to see if we just generated a duplicate of this value (either using the key itself or its corresponding value in the array, depending on whether `getVal` is `true`). If so, we return the result of calling `getRandom` again, once again passing the last random number that was used. This can happen as many times as necessary.

When one of these calls to `getRandom` produces a new number, then the expression in the first conditional will be false. In this case, we return the wanted value (via the second `return` statement) and all of the recursive calls to `getRandom` are "unrolled". (Remember, we returned the value of each call to `getRandom` at each step.)

Comment: very interesting. Thank you. To be honest, though, I'm having a hard time understanding it the logic in the "if" and the "return" line. If you have time to explain to a newbie, I would definitely appreciate it.

Comment: @Michael - Explanation added.